# Why my Array sort is not printing both methods (I have regular sort and reverse sort), its only printing one or the other?

Tags: arrays

I am trying to print the output of one array sorted in increasing order and decreasing order, but whenever I try to run Sysout print it will only print one method and not the other despite the fact that I have them both implemented.

I tried assigning my arr1 and arr2 the same sort and then it will print the same method but it will not print them separately.

I am not asking to debug my code, I am just wondering if this is an issue that I am missing like Threading.

Thank you.

//*****------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*****//

package Test1;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class HighestLowestActivity2 {

```
public int [] sort(int arr[]) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        // Inner nested loop pointing 1 index ahead
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {

            // Checking elements
            int temp = 0;
            if (arr[j] > arr[i]) {

                // Swapping
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }

        // Printing sorted array elements
        //System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
    return arr;
}

public int [] reverseSort(int arr[]) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        // Inner nested loop pointing 1 index ahead
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {

            // Checking elements
            int temp = 0;
            if (arr[j] < arr[i]) {

                // Swapping
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }

        // Printing sorted array elements
        //System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
    return arr;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    HighestLowestActivity2 obj1 = new HighestLowestActivity2();
    HighestLowestActivity2 obj2 = new HighestLowestActivity2();

    // Custom input array
    int arr[] = { 4, 0, 3, 56, 2, 32, 1 };
    
    int[] arr1 = new int[arr.length];
    int[] arr2 = new int[arr.length];
    arr1 = obj1.sort(arr);
    arr2 = obj2.reverseSort(arr);
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i< arr1.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr1[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }       
    
    System.out.println();
    
    for(int i = 0; i< arr2.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr2[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    System.out.println();
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(obj1.sort(arr)));
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(obj2.reverseSort(arr)));

}
```

}

Comment: OUTPUT:

0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
32 
56 

0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
32 
56 

[56, 32, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 32, 56]

Answer (score 0):

Java uses call-by-value to compute reference variables. That means that whenever you update a referenced variable, you also update the variables that references it. In your case, this leads to the following problem:

```
arr1 = obj1.sort(arr); // arr is sorted and then returned in the sort() method, then arr is assigned to arr1;
arr2 = obj2.reverseSort(arr); // arr is reverseSorted and then returned and assigned to arr2 BUT the value of arr is also updated for arr1
```

This is called side effects. You manipulate variables inside methods that are used outside of them. Side effects can be useful, but are generally considered a bad practice when you are not actively trying to use them.

You can solve this problem either by avoiding the side effects, using for example a separate array in the sort methods:

```
public int [] sort(int arr[]) {

    int returnArr[] = arr;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < returnArr.length; i++) {

        // Inner nested loop pointing 1 index ahead
        for (int j = i + 1; j < returnArr.length; j++) {

            // Checking elements
            int temp = 0;
            if (returnArr[j] > returnArr[i]) {

                // Swapping
                temp = returnArr[i];
                returnArr[i] = returnArr[j];
                returnArr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return returnArr;
}
```

Or you could do a quick and dirty fix, avoiding the consequences of the side effects while still incurring them, by putting the first for loop, which prints arr1 in separate lines, before the assignment for arr2:

```
arr1 = obj1.sort(arr);

for(int i = 0; i< arr1.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(arr1[i] + " ");
    System.out.println();
}

arr2 = obj2.reverseSort(arr);
```